# Error occurred during batching: ORA-06550: line 1, column 81: PLS-00103:

Tags: javascript, oracle, stored-procedures

Error:

> Error occurred during batching:
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 81:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SA_CI" when expecting one of the following: . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem => <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset ```

I am trying to put txt file as input for SQL command, below is content of file

```
{CALL TABLE_REFRESH("SA_CI","INSERT","S1212429247","asd--asd-mm","in build","downtime optimized","FC-ONLY","UNDEFINED","sa.sad.asd.asd.sd.asd.asd","","","","","","","","")};
{CALL TABLE_REFRESH("SA_CI","INSERT","S2122","sad--asd--2015-09-03","in build","downtime optimized","FC-ONLY","UNDEFINED","sa.sad.asd.asd.sd.asd.asd","","","","","","","","")};
{CALL TABLE_REFRESH("SA_CI","INSERT","S74986178","dcplnx7498456178","Retired","downtime optimized","FC-ONLY","UNDEFINED","sa.sad.asd.asd.sd.asd.asd","","","","","","","","")};
{CALL TABLE_REFRESH("SA_CI","INSERT","S75043501059","dcplnx75043501059","Retired","downtime optimized","FC-ONLY","UNDEFINED","sa.sad.asd.asd.sd.asd.asd","","","","","","","","")};
{CALL TABLE_REFRESH("SA_CI","INSERT","S7500200003","dcplnx7500200003","in build","downtime optimized","FC-ONLY","UNDEFINED","sa.sad.asd.asd.sd.asd.asd","","","","","","","","")};
```

I tried below solutions as in javascript to concat dynamic inputs

```
**1.** commandout += '{CALL TABLE_REFRESH(\"SA\_CI\",\"INSERT\",\"'+column_value_insert[0]+'\",\"'+column_value_insert[1]+'\",\"'+column_value_insert[2]+'\",\"'+column_value_insert[3]+'\",\"'+column_value_insert[4]+'\",\"'+column_value_insert[5]+'\",\"'+column_value_insert[6]+'\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\")};\n';

**2.** commandout += '{CALL TABLE_REFRESH(\'SA_CI\',\'INSERT\',\''+column_value_insert[0]+'\',\''+column_value_insert[1]+'\',\''+column_value_insert[2]+'\',\''+column_value_insert[3]+'\',\''+column_value_insert[4]+'\',\''+column_value_insert[5]+'\',\''+column_value_insert[6]+'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\')};\n';

Error is only with first two lines, below lines working fine.
```

Also if I tried to pass individual stored procedure calls, that's working fine.

Comment: if you build strings inside `''` you don't need to escape `"` ... not sure why you escape `_` ... if you want simpler looking code to build those strings, use string ES6 templates literals `\``\`

Comment: what does `below lines working fine` mean? below what?

Comment: where does `column_value_insert` array come from and what is its content

Comment: @JaromandaX  

```{CALL TABLE_REFRESH("SA_CI","INSERT","S1212429247","asd--asd-mm","in build","downtime optimized","FC-ONLY","UNDEFINED","sa.sad.asd.asd.sd.asd.asd,"","","","","","","","")};
```
this is the output formed by ```column_value_insert``` array.

Comment: `"sa.sad.asd.asd.sd.asd.asd,""` see something missing?

Comment: Among these Error lines mentioned ,  First 2 lines are throwing error, if i remove first 2 lines and pass file ... that will work fine. so there is something wrong with first 2 lines.

Comment: "sa.sad.asd.asd.sd.asd.asd,"" there are some null values as well

Comment: there's a missing `"`

Comment: there's a missing " --- Typo error... from my side ... just to maintain data privacy

Comment: can you see something distinctive about the first two lines compared with the others ... hint: notice something about `column_value_insert[1]` for those two lines that's absent in the other lines

Comment: Yes , ```--``` has been causing the issue. So searching solution to accept them as well .